# What's the way of running NUnit tests on .Net Core project which refers .NetStandard project including those tests?

Tags: .net-core, nunit, .net-standard

I have my tests defined in .NetStandard project (assembly) (as I need to test them through very different platforms).
We can't run those directly as it requires the project to target something like .NetFramework or .Net Core.

So, I've created .Net Core project and referencing my .NetStandard project.

However, when running `dotnet test ...csproj` I obviously receive

> No test is available in .... Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

... as there is obviously no magic and testing adapter can't read my mind and go to any referenced assembly automatically.

That seems that the tests discoverer just doesn't look at the attached assemblies with tests.

However, there must be some way of mentioning that to it, right?
[The documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/.NET-Core-and-.NET-Standard) is quite modest about that, so I don't even know if this approach in general possible.
However, when testing Xamarin.iOS/Android with TestRunners, they always have the option to add my assembly to test, like this: `runner.Add(typeof(MyTestClass).Assembly)`.

---

Just to be clear, that this question point **is not** actually about *targeting different platforms issue*, but finding the way of running tests from .Net Core project (the way it **already** works for Xamarin):

One of the solutions for this is creating an inherited class in .NET Core project from the class(es) of .NETStandard project:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestsClassInNetCoreProject : TestsClassInNetStandardProject
{
    // ...
}
```

(it would work both ways: either from command line or from VS "Run Tests" menu) but this is of course not the best way of handling this.

Just to summarize:

1. The tests should be placed in separate project/assembly as for Xamarin test projects they don't actually run in common way tests run (they run via a test runner inside of actually an iOS/Android app).
2. This way it's handy to have the tests in .NETStandard assembly, which can be attached anywhere else.
3. Again, this **already works** for Xamarin (platform-specific project attaching my .NETStandard library with tests) via a test runner (NUnit one), but it doesn't for .NET Core project.
4. I **don't need** to run the tests on the .NET Standard assembly itself (what is even not possible), I need **they to be referenced from** testable .NET Core project.

Is there any way I can be lucky with that?

Comment: What happens if you add a single test to the .NET Core project? Does it maybe run the whole lot?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "add a single test". The example I've provided above does that: it just overrides the tests class (I am not adding its new members here). Can't see other way of "connecting" those to .NET Core project. `dotnet run` just not locating those otherwise at all.